# How to display specific data in Excel depending on parameters passed from a webpage?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, excel, com

I've written a small piece of code which opens up an Excel document on a specific worksheet. This has been done in C#/ASP.NET using the Excel COM object.

I have now been tasked with extending this application to only display certain data in the Excel worksheet, depending on parameters which have been programmatically specified before interacting with the Excel COM object.

Unfortunately I do not have much information to work with, aside from the fact that the application is to make use of .NET technologies.

Could anyone mention some methods that such a program would be able to interact with an Excel worksheet, and display only certain data which satisfies the respective parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you want to use the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx) assembly to open the Excel work book and interact with it.

Add a COM reference to the **Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library**

Here is something to start you off:

```
var xlApp = new Application();
var workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
var sheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
sheet.Name = "Ours Only";
sheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Hello World";
xlApp.Visible = true;
```

What I have found very useful is googling `excel c# ExcelFeature` for example `excel c# conditional formatting`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've been using the Object Library myself. However, I was wondering whether or not it's possible to only display data in the spreadsheet which conforms to a specified set of parameters.

Do you know if it can be done with this COM library?

Comment: As in `if(myVariable>5) sheet.Cells[1,1]="This is big";`  Please could you elaborate on your question what you mean by parameters.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of details, but I haven't been presented with many details myself.

From what I can understand, it has to be something like this:

`if (company = "Microsoft")` then only display data related to Microsoft in the Excel spreadsheet. The condition/parameter is determined in the webpage.